# Force SDK support only one language

Tags: swift, frameworks

I have an application that supports several languages and a framework that has several screens that support the same languages my app support.

on button tapped, I call to the framework API that opens some screens.

The problem is that I want no matter what is my application's language
that the framework screens will support only English.

Is there is any way to force the language on the framework?

Comment: Just remove all other languages but English under Project > Localizations?

Comment: but if I do so and my app on rtl language then the framework will be rtl too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I removed all the localizations I don't want and before I call the framework API that opens a screen(in English) I use code to force left to right.

```
 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
 UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

and when I framework finished its work I return those params to default

```
   UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .unspecified
   UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .unspecified
```

That way even if my app is right to left language and the framework use English localization I can force it to display it left to right